# responsive mode - columns to rows

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

I am doing one of the freecodecamp challenges in order to learn more to get used to it, but I was trying to apply with a media query to do it in a responsive way and I haven't succeded it yet, probably you have suggestions for me?

The idea is to transform it in 2 rows, I've tried with flexbox and with Grid, but I don't know what I am doing wrong :(

I tried to paste the link of the code (Codepen, but it doesn't allow me to do it, so I leave you here below the code I am trying to.

> @media screen and (max-width: 600px) {   #body {
> display: flex;
> flex-direction: row;
> flex-wrap: wrap-reverse;   }
>
> ```
> #navbar {
> display: grid;
> grid-template-rows: 50%;   }
>  #main-doc {
> display: grid;
> grid-template-rows: 50%;   } }
> ```

I have something like this:

-- (25% 75%)

And that's what I want to achieve:

- (50%)
- (50%)

> https://codepen.io/nicovanur91/pen/PoGOjyR?editors=1100

Comment: Can you please define what "it" is? Are you referring to the layout of the page? I noticed that your `grid-template-columns` is set to `25% 75%` instead of your `grid-template-rows`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: before checking your code, when ever you call class into the CSS style you have to use `.` instead of `#` as long as `#` refers to element's ID, so check out your code and see how could this hint going to help you,

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).